# the variance of a function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-limit-theorems

I don't understuand how we can get get this variance :

if  $f : R \rightarrow R$ and $X_1,...X_n$  i.i.d then
$$
\operatorname{var}\left(f\left(X_{1}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}\left[\left(f\left(X_{1}\right)-f\left(X_{2}\right)\right)^{2}\right]
$$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your statement is a special case of the following general result:

> If $U$ and $V$ are i.i.d. then $\text{Var}(U) = \frac{1}{2} E[(U-V)^2]$.

Just expand the right-hand side to obtain $\frac{1}{2}(E[U^2] - 2E[UV] + E[V^2])$, and note that $E[UV] = E[U]E[V]=(E[U])^2$ and that $E[V^2]=E[U^2]$.

Comment: thanks @angryavian